# Effects of gravitational waves on light

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, curvature, gravitational-waves

My understanding is that light is curved by curvature in space-time lattice (that's why it can't escape a black hole, it is just too curved: I may be wrong). So how is light influenced by gravitational waves? Does it cause some kind of change in direction or frequency of the light, or anything else? Anything we can predict and then observe (even with very precise instruments)? Does anyone bothered with that problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238226/2451

Comment: See the answers in the duplicate, particularly the last one. Gravitational waves affect the spacetime, so affect the path taken by light. That was used by LIGO to detect gravitational waves, by changing the interference patterns of two perpendicular light beams.

Answer (score -1):

Light is a wave of particles.
 When gravity is very very strong(as in the case of a black hole) these particles are attracted towards the very center of the gravitational force(in the black hole case, towards the singularity).
  Feel free to correct the answer,thnx!